# Querying the database for basic auth using go-http-auth with martini-go

Tags: go, basic-authentication, martini

I am attempting to use go-http-auth with martini-go.  In the example given here - https://github.com/abbot/go-http-auth

```
package main

import (
        auth "github.com/abbot/go-http-auth"
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
)

func Secret(user, realm string) string {
        if user == "john" {
                // password is "hello"
                return "$1$dlPL2MqE$oQmn16q49SqdmhenQuNgs1"
        }
        return ""
}

func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *auth.AuthenticatedRequest) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "<html><body><h1>Hello, %s!</h1></body></html>", r.Username)
}


func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://blabla:blabla@localhost/my_db")
    authenticator := auth.NewBasicAuthenticator("example.com", Secret)
    m := martini.Classic()
    m.Map(db)
    m.Get("/users", authenticator.Wrap(MyUserHandler))
    m.Run()

}
```

The Secret function is using a hardcoded user "john".

The authentication is successful when I execute

```
curl --user john:hello localhost:3000/users
```

Obviously, this is a trivial example with hardcoded username and password.

I am now changing the `Secret` function to this

```
func Secret(user, realm string) string {

    fmt.Println("Executing Secret")

    var db *sql.DB

    var (
        username string
        password string
    )

    err := db.QueryRow("select username, password from users where username = ?", user).Scan(&username, &password)

    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        return ""
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    //if user == "john" {
        //// password is "hello"
        //return "$1$dlPL2MqE$oQmn16q49SqdmhenQuNgs1"
    //}
    //return ""
    return ""

}
```

But it fails with `PANIC: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference.` Which is obviously because I am attempting to instantiate `var db *sql.DB` in the `Secret` function.  I cannot pass `db *sql.DB` into the `Secret` function either because `auth.BasicNewAuthentication` is expecting a `Secret` argument that conforms to `type func (string, string) string`.

How can I implement my database query correctly and return the password for comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple closure to pass in a reference to your DB to the authenticator function:

```
authenticator := auth.NewBasicAuthenticator("example.com", func(user, realm string) string {
    return Secret(db, user, realm)
})
```

…and then change your `Secret` to accept the database as the first argument:

```
func Secret(db *sql.DB, user, realm string) string {
    // do your db lookup here…
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach to Attilas answer. You can define a struct, define the `Secret()` handler on it and pass only the referenced function (go keeps the reference to the "owner") into the `authhandler`.

```
type SecretDb struct {
  db *DB
}
func (db *SecretDb) Secret(user, realm string) string {
 // .. use db.db here
}


func main() {
   secretdb = SecretDb{db}
   ...
   auth.NewBasicAuthenticator("example.com", secretdb.Secret)
   ...
}
```